# Ошибка при описании creat() в lua FFI

Tags: lua, include

В книге работа с этой функцией описывается вот так:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int creat (const char *name, mode_t mode)
```

Однако, при выполнении в lua кода

```
ffi = require 'ffi'
ffi.cdef [[int creat (const char *name, mode_t mode)]]
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
stdin:1: unknown type mode_t on line 1
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'cdef'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Судя по всему, проблема возникает из-за того, что не описан тип при помощи `#include`. Как такую проблему можно решить?

**UPD**: последовав совету использовать `lcpp` пришёл вот к чему:

```
> lcpp = require("lcpp")
> ffi = require("ffi")
> ffi.cdef[[
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int creat (const char *name, mode_t mode)
]]
stack traceback:
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:232: in function 'error'
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:1382: in function 'compileFile'
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:746: in function </home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:745>
    (...tail calls...)
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:735: in function '_doWork'
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:742: in function </home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:742>
/home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:1367: /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:232: lcpp ERR [0000] file not found: sys/types.h
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'for iterator'
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:1367: in function 'compile'
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:1931: in function 'lcpp'
    /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/lcpp.lua:1939: in function 'cdef'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Comment: кстати, у вас скобка не закрыта: `ffi.cdef [[int creat (const char *name, mode_t mode]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для данной цели уместно было бы использовать эту [библиотеку](http://lcpp.schmoock.net/). Правда, сейчас она не подходит для этой цели, так как не умеет пользоваться путями из системных источников. Исправленая мною версия (открыт `pull request`) [здесь](https://github.com/v1993/lcpp).

Теперь подключение выглядит так:

```
ffi.cdef[[
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int creat (const char *name, mode_t mode)
]]
```

Answer (score 2):

вероятно, по аналогии с [вот этим](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html):

```
ffi.cdef[[
  typedef struct foo { int a, b; } foo_t;  // Declare a struct and typedef.
  int dofoo(foo_t *f, int n);  /* Declare an external C function. */
]]
```

вам надо добавить `typedef` для `mode_t`. (другой, более длинный найденный [пример](https://github.com/theganyo/lua2go/blob/master/lua/lua2go.lua)).

---

что именно подставить в качестве типа?

1. в `sys/types.h` тип `mode_t` определён как `__mode_t`:

   ```
   $ grep '\<mode_t' /usr/include/*/sys/types.h
   typedef __mode_t mode_t;
   ```
2. в `bits/types.h` тип `__mode_t` определён как `__MODE_T_TYPE`:

   ```
   $ grep '__mode_t' /usr/include/*/bits/types.h
   __STD_TYPE __MODE_T_TYPE __mode_t;      /* Type of file attribute bitmasks.  */
   ```
3. в `bits/typesizes.h` тип `__MODE_T_TYPE` определён как «синоним» `__U32_TYPE`:

   ```
   $ grep __MODE_T_TYPE /usr/include/*/bits/typesizes.h
   #define __MODE_T_TYPE           __U32_TYPE
   ```
4. в `bits/types.h` тип `__U32_TYPE` определён как «синоним» `unsigned int`:

   ```
   $ grep -r __U32_TYPE /usr/include/*/bits/types.h
   #define __U32_TYPE      unsigned int
   ```

---

т.е., судя по всему, вам надо вызывать `ffi.cdef` примерно так:

```
ffi.cdef [[
  typedef unsigned int mode_t;
  int creat (const char *name, mode_t mode);
]]
```

---

**обновление**:

а вот [тут](http://lcpp.schmoock.net/), например, предлагают напрямую использовать `#include` (для `mode_t` это будет `sys/types.h`):

```
ffi.cdef("#include <your_header.h>")
```

может быть, и так сработает.

Comment: «настоящие сишники» наверняка смогут подсказать более эффективный метод поиска всех этих макросов/определений.